# Transform 3D points to points in 2D image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, camera

Is there a way how I could transform 3D points to 2D points corresponding to the positions of a 2D image?

Is there a function in Python/OpenCV that has following properties:

input: 3D points, camera position in 3D, direction of the camera, maybe additional features of the camera

output: corresponding 2D points on the 2D image of the camera?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen `cv2.projectPoints` method?

```
Python: cv2.projectPoints(objectPoints, rvec, tvec, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs[, imagePoints[, jacobian[, aspectRatio]]]) → imagePoints, jacobian
```

The function computes projections of 3D points to the image plane given intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters.

more details [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void%20projectPoints(InputArray%20objectPoints,%20InputArray%20rvec,%20InputArray%20tvec,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArray%20imagePoints,%20OutputArray%20jacobian,%20double%20aspectRatio))

Comment: Thanks. On the link it is said that this function is about a pinhole camera. Am I right that a lens without distortion (distortion coefficients set to 0) would create the same results as a pinhole camera in this case?